# Counter example of LU decomposition uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

> **LU decomposition Theorem:** If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is such that each principal minor $A_k$ has $det(A_k) \neq 0, \, k = 1, 2, \dots, n-1$, then $A = LU$, beeing $L$ a lower triangular unit
> diagonal matrix and $U$ being an upper triangular matrix.

If $A$ is invertible I can prove the $LU$ decomposition is unique.

Is there a counterexample for the case $A$ is not invertible showing that its $LU$ decomposition is not unique?

Comment: @Moo The first example doesn't fit the theorem requirements, but I think the second link is a possible counter example. Thanks!

Comment: Every matrix admits a $PLU$ factorization, where $P$ is a permutation matrix. As for the counter example where $A$ is not invertible, consider $A = 0$. Then $A = LU$ for any unit diagonal $L$ and $U = 0$. Does this fit your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
0 & b
\end{pmatrix}$, $L=\begin{pmatrix}
l_{11} & 0\\
l_{21} & l_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$, $U=\begin{pmatrix}
u_{11} & u_{12}\\
0 & u_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$

If $A=LU$ then $\begin{pmatrix}
l_{11}u_{11} & l_{11}u_{12}\\
l_{21}u_{11} & l_{21}u_{12}+l_{22}u_{22}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
0 & b
\end{pmatrix}$

Now $l_{11}=l_{22}=1$, then $u_{11}=0, u_{12}=a, u_{22}=b-a\cdot l_{21}$, $A$ has infinite factorizations $LU$ whit $L$ unitary:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
0 & b
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
l_{21} & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
0 & b-a\cdot l_{21}
\end{pmatrix}$$